# how to replace all substrings of a array of strings in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, text-processing, string-substitution

I'm trying to list all files in a sub-directory without their path, I just want the file name and extension, but Bash substitution doesn't work with all paths in an array, it only works with the first element.

**Code:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

NAME="$(pwd | grep -o '[^/]*$')"

# ls src -R
PATH="$(ls src/*.{cpp,hpp} 2> /dev/null)"
if [ 0 -eq "${#PATH[@]}" ]; then
    echo "The project has no source code file yet."
    exit 0
fi

EMPTY=''
for FILE in "${PATH[@]}"; do
    echo "${FILE/src\//$EMPTY}"
done
```

**Directory tree:**

```
FileReader
├── bin
├── make.sh
├── obj
└── src
    ├── FileReader.cpp
    ├── FileReader.hpp
    └── main.cpp
```

**Expected:**

```
$ bash make.sh

FileReader.cpp
FileReader.hpp
main.cpp
```

**Output:**

```
$ bash make.sh

FileReader.cpp
src/FileReader.hpp
src/main.cpp
```

Comment: Could you use this - `( cd src ; ls *.{cpp,hpp} )`

Comment: Or find -printf "%f\n"

Comment: Paste your code at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Have a look at `dirname` , also avoid using upper case variables in bash to avoid varname collision, `PATH` is already taken. Also `PATH` in your code is not an array.

Comment: @MrR thanks for your solution, it worked!

Comment: @Jetchisel thanks for your recommendations, I removed an unused line thanks to [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net/) and also renamed all my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [parsing `ls` is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), I'd do something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# If no matching files, globs expand to an empty string instead of the pattern
shopt -s nullglob
declare -i count=0
for file in src/*.[ch]pp; do
    count+=1
    printf "%s\n" "$(basename "$file")"
done

[[ $count -eq 0 ]] && echo "The project has no source code file yet."
```

to avoid issue with funny characters in filenames. [`basename(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html) removes leading directory components from a filename (And optionally a given extension).

You can also safely get the files in an array with `files=( src/*.[ch]pp )` and use something closer to your original approach. I would **definitely** avoid calling a variable `PATH` though as that conflicts with a built in one, though.

Array based version (This one uses the `${variable#pattern}` parameter expansion syntax that strips the matched text of a pattern from the beginning of the variable's value):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
files=( src/*.[ch]pp )

if [[ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "The project has no source code file yet."
else
    printf "%s\n" "${files[@]#*/}"
fi
```

Comment: I kind of like the second version better, actually, because it removes the explicit for loop.

Comment: and removes all the sub-processes to do `basename` so if there were lots of files should be a heap faster.